# How to configure printing?

Tags: print

I'm trying to get to grips with printing from emacs.

I've added the following to my .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'lpr-switches "-P HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_")
(add-to-list 'lpr-switches "-o sides=two-sided-long-edge")
(add-to-list 'lpr-switches "-o number-up=2")
```

When I try to print (so far I've only tried with M-x print-region), the following is written to * Messages * (after a prompt about printing to the default destination):

> Spooling with options -P HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_...
> user-error: Spooling with options -P HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_...done: /usr/bin/lpr: No such file or directory

If I cut the displayed command and paste it to the command line, prefixed by `lpr`  and suffixed by a space and the name of an existing file, that file is printed without problem, which makes me think that I haven't mistyped the over-long printer name. What's going wrong?

I'm running Linux Mint Ulyana 20 and GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian

### UPDATE

From * Help * in response to C-h v exec-path

> exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
> Its value is
> ("/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin" "/opt/chromedriver" "/opt/fossil" "/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/usr/games" "/usr/local/games" "/snap/bin" "/usr/lib/emacs/26.3/x86_64-linux-gnu")

From the command line:

> $ which lpr

> /usr/bin/lpr

Comment: First, make sure that you can print from the command line. When you can do that reilably, the emacs part is trivial. From what you show above, right now you are missing packages: you need to resolve that first.

Comment: I can print from the command line with the command `lpr -P HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_ <filename>` Which packages am I missing?

Comment: I was wrong about the packages: that looks OK, It's just that your emacs cannot find `/usr/bin/lpr` for some reason. Check `exec-path` and post its value in your question.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're using `add-to-list`, which according to the docstring, will "Add ELEMENT to the value of LIST-VAR if it isn’t there yet."  At most your first call to `add-to-list` will work, unless `lpr-switches` is already non-`nil`, at which points none of your calls will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpr-switches` is a list of arguments.  So think of them as each element of the list being implicitly quoted.  E.g.:

```
(setq lpr-switches
      (append '("-P" "HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_"
                "-o" "sides=two-sided-long-edge"
                "-o" "number-up=2")
              lpr-switches))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's fixed it. Clearly I need to learn a bit more about writing Emacs lisp. Can you recommend a good book?

Comment: A parital answer, but you can also use `(setq printer-name "HP_ENVY_Photo_6200_series_685E88_")`